How to find the condition number of \begin{bmatrix} I & B\\ B^{T} & I \end{bmatrix}
I want to find the spectral condition number of this matrix, notice that this matrix is symmetric, hence the spectral condition number can be wriiten as $$\frac{\max_{1\leq i \leq n }|\lambda_{i}| }{\min_{1\leq i \leq n }|\lambda_{i}| }$$, in which $\lambda_i$ is he eigenvalue of the matrix \begin{bmatrix}
I & B\\
B^{T} & I
\end{bmatrix}, but now I'm stuck, I don't know how to find the eigenvalues of this matrix

If you subtract the identity matrix, you get $\begin{bmatrix}0 & B \ B^\top & 0\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues of this matrix are precisely the positive and negative singular values of $B$. Adding the identity back again simply adds $1$ to all of these eigenvalues.
